# How to find web element with python with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

i need to get the name AHPI from this html

```
<a class="jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu" href="/quote/nasdaq-ahpi" aria-label="View quote detail page of AHPI" style="width: 60px; text-align: left;">AHPI</a>
```

i tried :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu')
```

it does not find AHPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take it as

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'jss1qhutbl jss1jy44eu')]")

print(element.text)
```

OR

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu")

print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.jss1qhutbl.jss1jy44eu')
```